# Upgrading from kohana 2.3 to 3.3

Tags: kohana

I have a project written in kohana 2.3. It has to be rewritten to 3.3, and while doing this, I wanna clean the whole code up, fix some bugs etc. The project itself contains >10k lines of code.

What would you recommend me, rewriting everything from a scratch, or simply fixing everything step-by-step in the native code?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend writing everything from scratch. There is an enormous difference between Kohana version 2.3 and 3.3, so breaking down your code and building it up for 3.3 would cause more pain and problems than just writing from scratch.

You could also just keep your existing project at Kohana 2.x and revert to Kohana 3.x for any future projects. As long as your projects work without any problems, there is no reason to switch to 3.x.

For more information on Kohana 2.x vs 3.x, see this article: http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php?id=what_version_of_kohana_should_i_use

Answer (score 1):

This is potentially a very broad question and it is really hard to provide an answer that would be the most suitable for your project considering we know very little about it.

>10k lines isn't all that much to be honest and taking into account all the benefits that the new Kohana version may provide you it is definietly worth considering, but if the current project is already well designed and written simple adaptation to Kohana 3.3 might be enough.

You may want to refer to Kohana guide providing details on what's changed between versions starting with [2.x -> 3.0](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/upgrading), through [3.0 -> 3.1](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/upgrading), [3.1 -> 3.2](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/upgrading) ending with [the latest migration guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/upgrading) to get an idea what you'll be dealing with when adapting.

On the other hand it might be that the rewrite could be quicker to complete. It is very hard to judge and decide.